# Press "Send" button on Android keyboard. Send keyevent from ADB to a device

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to press "Send" button on the Android keyboard?
I've tried the code for KEYCODE_ENTER

```
adb shell input keyevent 66
```

but it doesn't work for "Send"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not.  So KeyEvents and the soft keyboard-  soft keyboards don't send key events.  They use the InputConnection to call functions, these functions do NOT correlate to key events.  KeyEvents are generally only used by hardware keys. Normally that's ok and you can pretend to be a physical slide out keyboard and most stuff will work.  The problem is that the Send key isn't the enter key.  Its an ime action.  The field you're in said in its setup to the keyboard that the SEND action is available.  There's a special function on the input connection you can use to send a SEND event.  This is not the same as the enter key, even though many keyboards use the same spot to input one-  its a separate event type.  Sending an enter wouldn't trigger it-  it would treat it as a \n.  You actually would need to specifically call that input connection function, and I don't think you can do that via command line.

Comment: So how can we invoke the Android SEND button on the current VIEW?